# solution for having standard menu functionality,

Tags: symfony, content-management-system, fosuserbundle, backend, sonata-admin

I'm learning Symfony2 and I'm trying 
to find a solution for my problem , 
What's the best solution for having standard menu functionality, like in CMSes (WordPress, Drupal, )? The solution that will allow admin to edit the menu and adding images , articles , alerts ..  from the back end and push it to the front end , 
The solution that will work with Sonata or some other admin bundle.

Comment: You more or less answered your own question: The best solution would be to develop a bundle that allows exactly that.

Comment: For someone new to Symfony, asking this question is understandable and it shouldn't get downvoted. Noone seems to have explained to OP that Symfony is a framework (a set of tools with a pipeline), not a CMS (content management system). The functionality you are looking for simply doesn't exist unless you choose to use something like Symfony CMF (Content Management Framework) which is a collection of components designed to act as a CMS, sorta. For baking the functionality yourself, see my answer below

Answer (score 0):

I'd say the [KNP menu bundle](http://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/KnpMenuBundle/index.html) is the closest you will get to a general purpose menu builder, it's what is already used in Sonata Admin if memory serves correct.

You'd still need to cookup an admin for the definitions and compiler for generating the menu's however.

The short answer is that, if you are needing menu builders in your solution, Symfony might not be the best bit of code to build on. Look up [Symfony Content Management Framework](http://cmf.symfony.com/) if you're determined to use Symfony

Symfony is about putting together a custom solution